# R plot with continuous column

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts, line

I am willing to do some line charts in R with these data below. For now, I get an error with my code. Any help will be welcome.

```
data <- structure(list(names = c("AB", "BBB", "CCC"), day1 = c(2L, 4L, 
14L), day2 = c(2.2, 10, 25), day3 = c(1.2, 12, 12), day4 = c(1.7, 
4, 12), day5 = c(2L, 10L, 14L)), .Names = c("names", "day1", 
"day2", "day3", "day4", "day5"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

data
#names day1 day2 day3 day4 day5
#AB     2    2.2 1.2   1.7  2
#BBB    4    10   12   4    10
#CCC    14    25   12  12    14


ggplot(data, aes(day1:day5, names, color = names)) + geom_line()
```

Comment: Could you show us the result of `dput(data)`?  Because we do not know here what it is: matrix, data.frame...?

Comment: data is a data.frame.

Comment: You can't use `day1:day5` as an `aes`. You need to specify 1 variable

Comment: I think you probably want something like this `df_m <- melt(df, id.var = "names");
ggplot(df_m, aes(value, names, color = names)) + geom_line()`

Comment: reshape with `tidyr::gather(data, key  = day, value  = value, -names)` then plot

Comment: Thanks guys it works  @krainer and @ work well. great rgunning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
data <- structure(list(names = c("AB", "BBB", "CCC"), day1 = c(2L, 4L, 
14L), day2 = c(2.2, 10, 25), day3 = c(1.2, 12, 12), day4 = c(1.7, 
4, 12), day5 = c(2L, 10L, 14L)), .Names = c("names", "day1", 
"day2", "day3", "day4", "day5"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

dat_m <- melt(data, id.var = "names")
ggplot(df_m, aes(variable, value, colour = names, group = names)) + geom_line()
```

This results in this plot:
[image: line plot]

Comment: Try to avoid answering question that are duplicates of other questions. Also, no need for the extra `group` specification if `colour` is a discrete.

Comment: thanks, I am grateful. it works well as I want.

Answer (score 0):

```
library("ggplot2")
library("reshape2")

data <- data.frame(
  "names"=c("AB","BBB","CCC"),
  "day1"=c(2,4,14),
  "day2"=c(2.2,10,25),
  "day3"=c(1.2,12,12),
  "day4"=c(1.7,4,12),
  "day5"=c(2,10,14)
)

test_data_long <- melt(data, id="names")  # convert to long format
ggplot(data=test_data_long,aes(variable,value, colour=names)) + 
       geom_line(aes(group = names))
```

[image]

Comment: Try to avoid answering question that are duplicates of other questions. Also, no need for the extra `group` specification if `colour` is a discrete.

Comment: thanks, I am grateful. it works well as I want. @rgunning